# Sorting algorithm used by Panda's sort_values when the kind parameter is not applied

Tags: python, sorting, pandas, dataframe

In Pandas' `sort_values` method, the `kind` parameter is only applied when sorting on a single column or label.  Why is this, and what sorting algorithm is used in these situations where the `kind` parameter is not applied? Is it a stable sort?

(See https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html for documentation.)

Comment: In reading the source, it looks like things get complicated.  If there is a single column, then it uses `quicksort` as that is the default value.  As far as I can tell when there is more than one column, [it looks like it does some binning of the data and then decides whether to do a "counting sort" or a "mergesort" depending on the number of groups.](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/master/pandas/core/sorting.py#L313).  Both of these algorithms are stable.

Comment: In this pandas [github issue](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/92), there is a mention that the sort on multiple columns _is stable_.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a [docstring from the source file](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/master/pandas/core/sorting.py#L313),  which declares `get_group_index_sorter(group_index, ngroups)`:

> ```
> algos.groupsort_indexer implements `counting sort` and it is at least
> O(ngroups), where
>     ngroups = prod(shape)
>     shape = map(len, keys)
> that is, linear in the number of combinations (cartesian product) of unique
> values of groupby keys. This can be huge when doing multi-key groupby.
> np.argsort(kind='mergesort') is O(count x log(count)) where count is the
> length of the data-frame;
> ```

---

> ```
> Both algorithms are `stable` sort and that is necessary for correctness of
> ```

---

> ```
> groupby operations. e.g. consider:
>     df.groupby(key)[col].transform('first')
> ```

PS here is a "call chain":

```
pandas.core.frame.DataFrame.sort_values() -> \
  pandas.core.sorting.lexsort_indexer() ->  \
    pandas.core.sorting.indexer_from_factorized() -> \
      pandas.core.sorting.get_group_index_sorter()
```

Comment: Where in `DataFrame.sort_values` is this method called?

Comment: @JanTrienes, it's bit complicated -  here is the calling tree: `sort_values -> lexsort_indexer -> indexer_from_factorized -> get_group_index_sorter`